# Error in submission parameters using CKEditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I am having a bit of issue with CKEditor posting form data.

My view code:

```
<%= form_for @form, url: "update", method: "post", :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
<form rows="200" cols="129">
        <%= f.error_messages %> 
            <%= f.cktext_area :htmldata1, :id => "htmldata1", :rows => '100', :cols => '129', :value => @form, :ckeditor => {:language => "us", :toolbar => "mini"}%>
            <input type="hidden" name="formName" value=<%=@formName%>>
          <p>
            <%= f.submit "Approve"%>
          </p>


    </form>
```

However, when I modify a document that has it's value passed in with :value => raw(@form) as a variable in the f.cktext_area, the form submission would look something like.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vLU9+Ojv97J9qlDYTyjjS25TiO/yrTxeAAAXLUDIJAw=", "first line of ckeditor field"=>{"htmldata1"=>"the entire ckeditor field"}, "formName"=>"a7205655-0f55-4d90-926e-676425d1e124filename.html", "commit"=>"Approve"}
```

My controller code for edit (The current form page) Edit is the filename param obtained from the prev page.

```
def edit
    @form = File.read("path/"+params[:Edit].to_s)
    @formName = params[:Edit].to_s
end
```

My update code

```
def update
    directory = "dir/"
    filename = params[:formName].to_s
    File.open(File.join(directory, filename), 'w') do |f|
      f.write(params[:htmldata1])
    end
    form = Form.find_by_filename(filename)
    form.status = 1
    form.save
    redirect_to "http://127.0.0.1:3000/forms?", :notice => "Successfully updated form."
  end
```

Server output of entire function:

```
Started POST "/forms/update" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-24 19:53:18 -0700
Processing by FormsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vLU9+Ojv97J9qlDYTyjjS25TiO/yrTxeAAAXLUDIJAw=", "<p>Testing 123</p>%0D%0A"=>{"htmldata1"=>"<p>Testing 123</p>\r\n\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n\r\n<p>I am groot</p>\r\n"}, "formName"=>"a7205655-0f55-4d90-926e-676425d1e124.html", "commit"=>"Approve"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Form Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `forms`.* FROM `forms` WHERE `forms`.`filename` = 'a7205655-0f55-4d90-926e-676425d1e124.html' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE `forms` SET `status` = 1, `updated_at` = '2017-05-25 02:53:18' WHERE `forms`.`id` = 13
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/forms?
Completed 302 Found in 8.0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Some help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Edit: I should probably add that it works completely fine when the document was initially blank but it does not if there is something already in it.

Comment: In your params, the key `"first line of ckeditor field"` seems strange, where is that key coming from? Can you post your controller code? You're going to need to whitelist the keys that you want your @form to save. For that matter, @form seems like a bad name, do you have a `Form` model?

Comment: I do have a Form model and I have updated the post with my controller code. Its pretty strange as well as if the html file I open is empty and and type in something and submit it, the parameters will reflect 'htmldata1' => 'whatever I typed in' correctly.

Comment: Just to clarify "first line of ckeditor field" means the first line of whatever is in the field currently after I submit the form.

Comment: The only thing I'm seeing off of the bat is that `params[:htmldata1]` is nested, so it is probably `nil` -- thereby writing nothing to the file. Can you test this by doing `puts params[:htmldata1]`? And then checking your server output? While you're at it, posting the server output of this whole action would probably help. :-)

Comment: puts params[:htmldata1] returns nothing

Comment: So, usually your params would be nested in `form_for` under the object declared as the first argument. But, I really don't understand why your key pointing to `htmldata1` seems to be dynamic. If you could explain that or change that, I believe I could answer your question.

Comment: Oh my, I think I see where you may be having the issue. You have an `<form>` nested inside of your `<%= form_for %>`. This will be a problem, as the `form_for` tag generates a `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review the comments for how the solution was discovered, but the essence of it was giving a `name` attribute to the `f.cktext_area` as discovered by the OP.

You need to remove the extra html `<form>`.

```
<%= form_for @form, url: "update", method: "post", :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %> 
  <%= f.cktext_area :htmldata1, :id => "htmldata1", :rows => '100', :cols => '129', :value => @form, :ckeditor => {:language => "us", :toolbar => "mini"}%>
   <input type="hidden" name="formName" value=<%=@formName%>>
   <p>
     <%= f.submit "Approve"%>
   </p>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller, in your update method:

```
def update
  ...
  File.open(File.join(directory, filename), 'w') do |f|
    f.write(params[:form][:htmldata1])
  end
  ...
end
```

That way the the nested data will be properly grabbed.

Comment: Hi, the removal of the extra <form> changed nothing. An new empty CKEditor input will post properly with htmldata1 as it's key, however, a non-empty one will post with the first line of the CKEditor input as it's key and the value would be the entire CKEditor input.

Comment: Okay then! Well, you're going to need to figure out how to set that key that keeps changing to grab you data. That seems to be the central issue here.

Comment: The issue is there is no dynamic key in play at the moment in my code, which is why the entire thing is so strange, there is a specific key set to the f.cktextarea, why is it posting with another key.

Comment: Ah I just fixed it, I added an attribute to the f.cktext_area, :name => 'htmldata1' and it is posting with the correct key, thanks for your help! Although I still have no idea why it defaults the key to the first line and how it sometimes works and it sometimes doesn't.

Comment: Ah! There you go! Wonderful. Yeah, that's funny. Usually the `name` is generated by the `form_for @model`, but I'm guessing that b/c `@form = File.read(...)`, it didn't know how to generate the name...

Comment: Hmmm, that may explain why it doesn't work, thanks for your help!

Comment: Of course! Yeah, I'm pretty sure that's it. That's why the key kept changing to the first line of the file's text! All makes sense! :-)